# iOS Go back to parent view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, paypal

I'm using payal iOS SDK and i want to go back to parent view controller in the function sendCompletedPaymentToServer using :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

and :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
```

app crashed.
ParentViewcontroller can be different.

it happens when i click on pay button for the second time.
ERROR Log :

2016-03-07 11:49:52.212 Ova[7169:2862312] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for .
2016-03-07 11:50:02.525 Ova[7169:2862312] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArray0 objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184915900 0x183f83f80 0x184891478 0x100145268 0x10014494c 0x100144ba4 0x10011a200 0x100116a9c 0x10010aafc 0x100150200 0x1010cdbf0 0x1010cdbb0 0x1010d3658 0x1848ccbb0 0x1848caa18 0x1847f9680 0x185d08088 0x189670d90 0x10006ec28 0x18439a8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: can you please add crash log data.?

Comment: From `exception` looks like you are trying to access nil  `Array index` .

Comment: Yes cause after payment all objects are removed from array and should come back to parent view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are using :

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will bring you back to view controller. If you want to navigate back to previous view controller,you should implement :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: i got this :Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for myViewController and nothing happen. When i click to pay again app crashed.

Comment: Move your code into viewDidAppear and the warning should go away. The problem with viewDidLoad is that the UINavigationController hasn't finished its animation yet. So, the navigation controller's animation is still happening when the modal's animation happens.

Comment: My code is into sendCompletedPaymentToServer method. i use Paypal SDK and i want to go back to parentViewController after paypal payment sccess. when i use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil] it comes back to my first ViewController not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding BOOL variable to test if payment success or not. And into viewWillAppear i use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

We also had same issue while integrating PayU gateway.
 I suggest you to use **Protocol Delegate method** to present view controller in which you are loading Payal in its web view.
Let second view controller is the one in which you are loading Payal and First view controller is presenting second view controller.
1. In Second view controller declare protocol that will dismiss secondviewcontroller

```
@protocol DismissPayalDelegate <NSObject>
@required
     -(void)dismissPayal:(id)viewcontroller;
@end

 @interface secondviewcontroller : UIViewController
     @property(strong, nonatomic) id < DismissPayalDelegate > delegate;   
 @end
```

in secondviewcontroller.m file synthesize delegate object.
In first view controller, If you are using performSegeuWithIdentifier (to present 2nd vc i.e Payal) then use get instance of destinationviewController i.e  secondviewcontroller.
set `destinationviewcontrollerInstance.delegate = self;`
In secondViewController's Success/Failure method write code to dismiss view controller

```
[delegate dismissPayal:self];<br><br>
```

It will dismiss instance of second view controller that was presented in performSegueWithIdentifier method
**Use this logic, I hope it helps you a lot.**

Comment: Ok i will try it. I think it's better than my solution. Thanks